# Cakephp 2 acl not denying any actions

Tags: cakephp, acl

I followed the tutorial and didn't get any errors but acl is allowing all actions for all users.I checked with aclmanager all permissions are being displayed correctly.I have added parent::beforeFilter(); in all controllers.Am I missing something? Can anybody please help me out with this?

This is my initDB function

```
public function initDB() {
$group = $this->User->Group;

$group->id = 1;
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

$group->id = 2;
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Employees');

 $group->id = 3;
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
//we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
echo "all done";
 }
```

This is my beforefilter function in appcontroller

```
function beforeFilter(){
$this->Auth->authorize = array(
    'Controller',
    'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
    );
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' =>          'username', 'password' => 'password')));   
 $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' =>   'employee_list');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enabled the acl component?

Check your `AppController` for sometime like:

```
public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
);
```

Comment: Also make sure your acl database tables such as `acos` are populated.

Comment: Yes I checked Acl component is enabled and acos,aros,aros_acos tables are populated.